# Program that returns a list of drive letters

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In the example of my computer the desired output should be: "C: E: F: H: N:" . I know it's possible, but what is the simpliest way to do that? Pottering in QueryDosDevice output

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif


#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

const int REPORT_LENGTH = 5000;

int main(void)
{
    TCHAR targetPath[REPORT_LENGTH];

    std::ofstream oFile;

    oFile.open("dos device query.txt");

    QueryDosDevice(NULL,targetPath,REPORT_LENGTH);

    for(int i=0; i<REPORT_LENGTH;i++)
    if (targetPath[i]=='\0')(targetPath[i]='\n');



    for(int i=0; i<REPORT_LENGTH; i++)
    oFile<<static_cast<char>(targetPath[i]);

    oFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

would be a huge waste of time and resources. Also function [GetLogicalDriveStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has betrayed me a lot.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    TCHAR buffer[50];

    GetLogicalDriveStrings(50,buffer);

    MessageBox(0,buffer,"Drives in the system",MB_OK); 


    return 0;
}
```

It shows only the "C:\" volumine.

Comment: You'll certainly have bad experiences with GetLogicalDriveStrings if you continue to interpret its output incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example with `GetLogicalDrives`, albeit not with concatenating to a string (which is left as an exercise to the OP and the readers ;)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int __cdecl _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[])
{
    // Get the bit mask of drive letters
    DWORD drives = ::GetLogicalDrives();
    // Go through all possible letters from a to z
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        // Check if the respective bit is set
        if(drives & (1 << i))
        {
            // ... and if so, print it
            _tprintf(TEXT("Drive %c: exists\n"), _T('A') + i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`GetLogicalDriveStrings()` is the way to go, you just have to use to correctly.  You are assuming it returns a single string containing all of the drive strings, but that is not true.  It returns an array of strings, one for each drive, so you have to loop through the array instead:

```
#include <windows.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    TCHAR buffer[(4*26)+1] = {0}; 
    GetLogicalDriveStrings(sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(TCHAR), buffer); 

    for (LPTSTR lpDrive = buffer; *lpDrive != 0; lpDrive += 4)
        MessageBox(NULL, lpDrive, "Drive in the system", MB_OK);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: could you explain your edit? I know for all practical purposes this won't change anything, but from what I read `%c` does not depend on the defines but is rather always `char`, so I'd like to find out why exactly this is an improvement. Thanks.

Comment: `%c` is NOT always `char`. `_tprintf()` maps to either `printf()` or `wprintf()` depending on whether `_UNICODE` is defined. `%c` is `char` in `printf()` and `wchar_t` in `wprintf()`. An `'A'` literal by itself is always `char`, but wrapped as `_T('A')` it becomes `_TCHAR` and thus maps to either `char` or `wchar_t` based on `_UNICODE`. If you want to use `char` input in `wprintf()`, you have to use `%C`, `%hc`, or `%hC` instead.